# Как изменить стили не дочернего элемента при :hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как при наведении на `.work__2` поменять стили `.photo__2`?

При помощи чего угодно (если кто знает о существовании специального плагина для таких вещей, то поделитесь пожалуйста)?

```css
.photo {
  float: left;
}
.photo__1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
.photo__2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 10px;

}
.photo__3 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  margin: 10px;

}

.carrer {
  float: left;
}
.work__1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
.work__2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 10px;
}
.work__3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo">
  <div class="photo__1"></div>
  <div class="photo__2"></div>
  <div class="photo__3"></div>
</div>

<div class="carrer">
  <div class="work__1">work 1</div>
  <div class="work__2">work 2</div>
  <div class="work__3">work 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: одним css - никак, так как отсутствуют необходимые селекторы

Comment: Я уже вкурсе. Мне просто надо чтоб при наведении на один елемент менялась картинка в другом елементе.
Питался через CSS методом display:none; display:block; получается только при условии что у них один родитель.

Comment: Вы хотите все это сделать на `css`?

Comment: Нет, можно использовать что угодно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот с применением `jquery`. Добавляем или удаляем класс нужному элементу. А в `css` элементу с этим классом даем нужные нам свойство.
Но что бы облегчить нам жизнь можно еще добавить в элементы с классом `work` атрибуты `data-photo` и в них прописать классы нужных элементов с классом `photo`. Тех что при наведении должны изменять. И так уже реализация `js` облегчается.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.carrer>div').on('mouseover', function(){
    $('.'+$(this).data('photo')).addClass('active');
  }).on('mouseout', function(){
    $('.'+$(this).data('photo')).removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.photo {
  float: left;
}
.photo__1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
.photo__2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 10px;

}
.photo__3 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  margin: 10px;

}

.carrer {
  float: left;
}
.work__1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
.work__2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 10px;
}
.work__3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  margin: 10px;
}

.photo>div.active{
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="photo">
  <div class="photo__1"></div>
  <div class="photo__2"></div>
  <div class="photo__3"></div>
</div>

<div class="carrer">
  <div class="work__1" data-photo="photo__1">work 1</div>
  <div class="work__2" data-photo="photo__2">work 2</div>
  <div class="work__3" data-photo="photo__3">work 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с использованием индекса элемента внутри блока

```js
$(".carrer").on("mouseenter mouseleave", ">", function(event) {
  var indx = $(this).prevAll().length;
  $(".photo>").eq(indx).toggleClass("active", event.type == "mouseenter");
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.carrer,
.photo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.block>div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: .8s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.carrer>div {
  width: 100px;
}

.block>div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
}

.block>div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.block>div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: green;
}

.block>div.active {
  border: 4px solid rgba(139, 69, 19, 1);
  border-radius: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="photo block">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="carrer block">
  <div>work 1</div>
  <div>work 2</div>
  <div>work 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Ребята, всем спасибо. Сделал таким способом. Работает как по маслу.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <div class="photo">
              <div class="photo photo__1 active"></div>
              <div class="photo photo__2"></div>
              <div class="photo photo__3"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="carrer">
              <div class="work work__1" data-photo="photo__1">work 1</div>
              <div class="work work__2" data-photo="photo__2">work 2</div>
              <div class="work work__3" data-photo="photo__3">work 3</div>
            </div>  


        .photo {
          float: left;
        }
        .photo__1 {
          width: 300px;
          height: 100px;
          background: red;
          margin: 10px;
          display: none;
        }
        .photo__2 {
          width: 300px;
          height: 100px;
          background: yellow;
          margin: 10px;
          display: none;
        }
        .photo__3 {
          width: 300px;
          height: 100px;
          background: green;
          margin: 10px;
          display: none;
        }

        .carrer {
          float: left;
        }
        .work__1 {
          width: 100px;
          height: 100px;
          background: red;
          margin: 10px;
        }
        .work__2 {
          width: 100px;
          height: 100px;
          background: yellow;
          margin: 10px;
        }
        .work__3 {
          width: 100px;
          height: 100px;
          background: green;
          margin: 10px;
        }

        .active{
          display: block;
        }  

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.work').on('mouseover', function(){
        $('.photo').removeClass('active');
        $('.'+$(this).data('photo')).addClass('active');
      });
    });
```